# What is this Toolbar-Style Cocoa UI Element?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, user-interface, standards, element

I've seen this toolbar-like UI element in a couple of apps, and I'd like to know if there's a standard Cocoa object for such an element.

- Xcode: [image: Xcode's Toolbar]
- ColorSchemer: [image: ColorSchemer's Toolbar]
- CornerStone: [image: CornerStone's Toolbar]

If a standard Cocoa implementation does not exist, can anyone suggest a good open-source library?

Comment: These are just buttons on an `NSView` with an image background.

Comment: @RobKeniger that's disappointing, but makes sense :) If you post it as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example, the buttons are what Interface Builder calls "Gradient Buttons" which have that appearance without needing a background image. The buttons are just butted up next to one another.

In the other examples, the "toolbar" is just an ordinary `NSView` with a custom image background, with standard `NSButton` objects as subviews. The buttons have their border disabled so all you see is the icon.

To get the "inset" look for the icons, the button images are most likely [template images](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsimage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000344-SW10). To make an image a template image, it must consist of black and clear colors only, with an alpha channel. You then call `[image setTemplate:YES]` on the `NSImage` object.

Apple supplies some [pre-canned template images](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000344-SW53) which you can access by using the `+imageNamed:` method of `NSImage`.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of Xcode, it's a private class called `IDENavigatorFilterControlBar`, with this inheritance hierarchy:

```
IDENavigatorFilterControlBar
IDEFilterControlBar
DVTBorderedView
DVTAutoLayoutView
NSView
```

DVT is the prefix used by the private Developer Tools framework.

Comment: Well that's disappointing. But clearly there has to be some alternative; because ColorSchemer, ConerStone, etc. wouldn't have access to those private APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but have you tried Matt Gemmell's [MGScopeBar](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/10/28/mgscopebar/)?

Comment: Nope. A cool piece of UI, but not at all what I'm looking for.